# Get the 'href' tag after text using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

What i want to get is the 'href' with the corresponding text whenever i search for the word which has href link. In this example if i search for the word 'over' from the 'div' below, i need it to display "over + 'href' ".

```
Sample of the html i used :
html '''
<div class="ez" style="" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;*s&quot;&#125;"> 
<span><p>This is the text here</p> <a href=" my link 3 ">More</a>
<div class="bl" style="" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;*s&quot;&#125;">
<span><p>Hello everybody over there</p><a href="my link 1></div><div 
class="ol"...><div class="bq qr"><a> class "gh" href="my link 2"</a>
'''html

enter code here 
    for text_href in soup.findAll('div'):
        word = text_href.text
        link = text_href['href']
        print(word '+' link)
for list in word:
    pattern =re.compile(r'over', re.I|re.UNICODE)
    matches = pattern.finditer(c)
        for match in matches:
            print(match) + print(link)
```

So the out put i was expecting is to flag out the match which is 'over' in my case the and the link(href) which the match 'over' located.
result:
over + 'the link i want to obtain'(which is the href)

Comment: Do you see `a href="my link 1></div>` and `<a> class "gh" href="my link 2"</a>`? They are not valid html tags, First one does not have quotes and other href is out the the tag. Beautiful Soup might not be able to work with them well. Use valid html and mention in the question what is needed/not working. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [find_next](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method if the link is always going to appear after the search text.

Something like this -

```py
html_doc ='''
<div class="ez" style="" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;*s&quot;&#125;"> 
<span><p>This is the text over here</p> <a href="the link i want to obtain 
">More</a>
<div class="bl" style="" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;*s&quot;&#125;">
<span><p>Hello everybody</p> <a href="www.mylink...">More</a>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

search_string = 'over'

print(search_string, '+', soup.find(string=re.compile(search_string, re.I)).find_next('a')['href']) # over + the link i want to obtain
```

You can update the regex accordingly if you are looking for whole words.

Comment: Thank you so much. you save my time

Comment: Hello, i updated the code above, could you tell me why i am not able to get the first 'href' which is 'my link 1'......when i try like u told me :print(search_string, '+', soup.find(string=re.compile(search_string, re.I)).find_next('a')['href']) : it gives me the 2nd href 'my link 2'

Comment: @DaviLeo update your question instead of answer. And post valid HTML; in the edit you suggested, `href` attribute was not properly quoted. Please update your question with the query. You can use an online html validator or render the document in a browser and post the code from there. Beautiful soup will not be able to work with invalid html very well

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
for text_href in soup.findAll('div'):
    word = text_href.text
    if 'over' in word:
        print(text_href.a['href'])
```

Output:

```
 the link i want to obtain
```

Comment: But there are 2 'href' which 'href' will it print?

Comment: @DaviLeo - Well, you changed the html since I posted the answer, but in any case even in the new html, the code will only print the first, the one with the word "over". Try it yourself.

Comment: I tried it but showing this error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @DaviLeo  That probably means that the sample html you posted isn't representative of the actual code you have. You may have to post more of the html. But given you sample html, the code definitely works.